# Problems connecting to pi 3 via ttl (cp2102)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, uart

I'm following raspberrypi.org [THE RASPBERRY PI UARTS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) guide, trying to connect from mac 10.13.6 High Sierra to Pi 3 using screen.

I had to disable system integrity protection on mac (high sierra) to get the cp1202 kext loaded. Once i did that, i was able to see the /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART. I tried connecting using screen, but saw only garbage characters. I have disabled hciuart service, disabled serial login shell (kinda odd, but that's what the guide suggests), still only seeing garbage.

To clarify, I'm trying to establish a serial connection from mac to PI, so i can get to PI's shell via screen (for example) from mac.

Any help is much appreciated!

[cp2102 drivers](https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers) I'm using

### end of /boot/config.txt

```
# Additional overlays and parameters are documented 
/boot/overlays/README
# Disabling Bluetooth overlay
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# NOOBS Auto-generated Settings:^M
hdmi_force_hotplug=1^M
enable_uart=1
gpu_mem=128
```

### /boot/cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

### /lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/proc/device-tree/soc/gpio@7e200000/bt_pins
Before=bluetooth.service
After=dev-serial1.device

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/btuart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar device (but not for some time). On the Mac this appears as `/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART`. (AFAIK there is no need to disable SIP - the driver should be included).

I am not sure why you fiddled with the Bluetooth on the Pi but if you don't do this `dev/serial0` should work (provided UART is enabled). See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

It is also unclear exactly what you expect `hciuart.service` to do (or if you have modified it) or indeed exactly what you are trying to do with the serial interface.

EDIT

If you want a Console use `raspi-config` to enable "login shell". You DO NOT need to fiddle with Bluetooth settings (the mini UART is more than capable of acting as a console).

I just tried on latest Raspbian - this gives login prompt, but there are a number of errors. I used the following.

```
screen /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART 9600,cs8,-echo,-parenb,-echo
```

Unfortunately I do not know the cause, this used to work with older versions of Raspbian. I suspect a clocking error with the new governor.

EDIT2
I decided to do some further investigation. Using `Serial Tools` on the Mac (this is a free download from the Apps Store - and much friendlier than the arcane `Screen`) and `minicom` on the Pi serial communication seems to operate normally.

Any problems seem to only impact on the Serial Console.

Comment: Based on the instructions in the guide i referenced pi3-disable-bt disables the Bluetooth device and restores UART0/ttyAMA0 to GPIOs 14 and 15, and t is also necessary to disable the system service that initialises the modem so it doesn't use the UART: sudo systemctl disable hciuart. 

pi3-miniuart-bt switches the Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi Zero W Bluetooth function to use the mini UART (ttyS0), and restores UART0/ttyAMA0 to GPIOs 14 and 15.

Similar things are written in the link you posted. Still, connecting from mac to pi does not give me shell, and when i reboot i see garbage.

Comment: @Alex I don't see how anyone could follow that "guide" - I have used serial on both the Mac and Pi (and lots of other devices over the last 50 years) but I don't understand all the waffle in it. What are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve? NOTE **DO NOT** post detail in Comments - edit into your question.

Comment: after fighting with this thing some more, I was finally able to get to login prompt. The last thing i did that might've helped was i updated packages, and the distro.